# Java issue converting String to double

Tags: java, double

I'm trying to convert a String into double.

The source string is in the format "88.6" and the double I expect should be "88.60".

I tried converting using Double.parseDouble, Double constructor, Double.valueOf, DecimalFormat and NumberFormat hardcoding Locale.US or Locale.ENGLISH but I still get "88,600000".

How should I convert it?

Thanks

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));
try {
    dValue = df.parse(szValue).doubleValue();
} catch(ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about formatting? The 88.6, 88.60 and 88.600000 are mathematically the same.

Comment: What different bit patterns of `double` do you expect between 88.6, 88.60 and 88.600000? (Hint: they're all the same value. `double` doesn't "know" about trailing insignificant zeroes... If you care about that, you might want to use `BigDecimal`.)

Comment: I tried also with BigDecimal, no way..
I need "88.60" and not "88,60"

Comment: I suspect it is a matter of output not conversion. Can you show your printing-line?

Comment: This value is a parameter of a query to MySQL
String query = String.format(Query.brands, id, dBasePot);

Query.brands contains %f to format the double dBasePot

Comment: Where do you get the "88,600000" we actually don't see it from your code.

Comment: Doubles are imperfect approximations to real numbers. To have a precision use **BigDecimal**. The comma/period + thousand-separators issue is one of the used Locale for localized formats. Maybe use Locale.US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't think that keeping trailing zeros is necessary, I think this is what you are asking for:

```
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    java.text.DecimalFormat df = new java.text.DecimalFormat();  
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
    df.applyPattern( "###0.00" );
    String s = "9.90" ;
    System.out.println("non formated d=" + Double.valueOf(s) + " formated d=" +df.format(Double.valueOf(s)));
```

the trailing zeros are only visible when printing them, so you just need to format the number

Comment: It seems that if I use a format string with %f it uses comma as decimal separator while concatenating string it uses dot

Comment: you can set decimal separator, imma edit the code, just set it to comma or dot or anything u like

Comment: your code now prints as expected, but as soon as I use it in a format string with String.format("string containing %f", value) it still uses comma as decimal separator

Comment: That's most likely because of your default Locale settings are changing it back, and the string.format uses the locale you have regardless of any changes you made in the string/number. thats why I made a formatter to print the number.
My default locale is Spanish and it prints the numbers with commas as well, but if you change it to the english one it will print them with dots. This is how http://pastebin.com/pd1VzQ2G

Comment: Thanks for explanation. So all problems were related to Locale settings..
Anyway, thanks for help